# silverlight - opening a file

Tags: c#, silverlight, file

I'm brand new to silverlight and looking for a little direction. I have a simple gallery app written with silverlight. I'd like to be able to in this example, just ftp a xml or json file  to the server in a folder the app knows to look in, and have the silverlight app open the file. The file would contain a gallery category, it's title desc, images and their title, desc. I would deseralize this data to use to show the new uploaded category. I've done this sort of thing many times in wpf, but can't see to figure out the best way to handle this in silverlight. Thanks for any direction, and please let me know if I need to provide more info. I'd also upload the images, the xml or json file would contain the information to link to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the WebClient for this. 
Here is a little example:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetFileContent("http://localhost/test/myjson.txt", ProcessResult, error => { throw error; });
        }

        private void ProcessResult(String result)
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }

        private void GetFileContent(String uri, Action<String> onData, Action<Exception> onError)
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();

            DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler handler = null;

            handler = (s, args) =>
            {
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= handler;
                if(args.Error != null)
                {
                    if(onError != null)
                        onError(args.Error);
                    return;
                }

                if(onData != null)
                    onData(args.Result);
            };
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += handler;
```

wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));
            }

You might have a look here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), because you need a clientaccesspolicy to access the file.

Is this what you need?

BR,

TJ

Comment: Thanks for answering, I want to make sure I understand something. Even though my app, and the album xml or json file, as well as the images are sittings on the same server, something like /installed at root of my account, and the album xml file is at at something like /album and the images are at maybe /Album/Images, I need to download the xml file? Is this because the silverlight app is run on the client side? and needs to grab the files from the server?

Comment: Yes, you need to download it, cause the sl app is running on the client. You could put the file in your xap, then you would'nt have to download it again. But then you are not really dynamic, 'cause each time you change the file, you have to recompile and redeploy.